# HTML5ですが、strongタグをつけなくても文字が太くなります。

Tags: html, html5

お世話になります。
HTML5ですが、strongタグをつけなくても文字が太くなります。
実行環境はGoogle Chromeです。

どのようにしたら、strongタグを付けない文字列が太くならないのでしょうか？
ご教授願います。

以下、ソースコードです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>初めてのHTML</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>大見出し<h1>
        <h2>中見出し<h2>
        <h3>小見出し<h3>
        <p>こんにちは！<br>こんにちは！</p>
        <p>こんにちは！</p>
        <p>こんにちは！</p>
        <p>こんにちは！</p>
        <p>こんにちは！</p>
        <p>こんにちは！</p>
        <p><strong>こんにちは！</strong></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<h1>大見出し<h1>` 閉じタグが間違っています。`<h1>大見出し</h1>`のように修正します。他のHタグも同様。

Comment: BLUEPIXY様

ありがとうございます＾＾解決しました＾＾

Answer (score 1):

h1 h2 h3の閉じタグが間違っています

Answer (score 0):

hタグはデフォルトでfont-weight: boldが有効になります。
hタグに

```
h2, h3, h4 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

で解決できます。

よって

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>初めてのHTML</title>
        <style>
        h2, h3, h4 {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>大見出し</h1>
        <h2>中見出し</h2>
        <h3>小見出し</h3>
        <p>こんにちは！<br>こんにちは！</p>
        <p>こんにちは！</p>
        <p>こんにちは！</p>
        <p>こんにちは！</p>
        <p>こんにちは！</p>
        <p>こんにちは！</p>
        <p><strong>こんにちは！</strong></p>
    </body>
</html>
```